# 3.3 V from 3.6 V, best way to do it?

Tags: power-supply, low-power

I have a 3.6 V power rail coming out of a buck/boost IC that I need to reduce to 3.3 V for an ultra-low-power design.

The power supply is four AA batteries, so 6.5 Vmax -> 3.6 V -> 3.3 V. Unfortunately due to my design I need both 3.6 V and 3.3 V domains.

I was thinking an LDO would be the best option to drop the extra 0.3 V, but I want to make absolutely sure that it will only add a few μA to my solution.

Can anyone recommend any implementations and SMD parts they recommend for this purpose?

Comment: You are already using a buck-boost, so what range exactly is low current? What's the lowest highest current draw during normal operation? Is 3.3 V the absolute maximum the circuit can take or the upper limit where it hits the specification?

Comment: You can also run the LDO directly off of the battery as an "always on" supply. That way you can turn off the buck/boost when you want to achieve extreme low power operation, and minimize all the loads on 3.3. Just an idea.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, depends on the details. There are probably more solutions than in the "duplicate".

Comment: Easiest way is to use a small Schottky diode in series.   The forward voltage drop of a typical Schottky is about 0.3V  i.e. 1N5817.   NOT a 'silicon' diode such as 1N4148.. those are typical 0.7V.  There has to be some current flowing to get a voltage drop, keep that in mind.  If the current = 0, then the drop =0 and the load is seeing 3.6V (so make sure it can tolerate that)    A CPU in 'sleep' mode is an example of the kind of load that would be about zero current.

Comment: there's a good chance that 3.45 is close enough for both domains

Comment: @mkeith my supply voltage is rather high to drop with an LDO, going from 6.5V to 3.3/3.6V would dump a huge amount of the power as heat, right?

Comment: @Ralph my target current is on the order of 60uA for the whole board, my main chip can go down to 14uA average current when supplied with 3.6V/3.3V on its different pins (3.6V goes to VDDH on nRF52840). Unfortunately, I am also interfacing with external hardware, so I have a design requirement that means IO supply voltage has to be 3.3V +/- 5%.

Comment: @KyleB problem with the schottky is as descibed in the duplicate question. There might be a suitable diode for 14-60 uA though, as long as having the voltage too high at 0-14 uA doesn't cause damage.

Comment: In very low-power applications, a linear regulator with low quiescent current will often consume less power than a DC-DC converter. If you are only consuming 60 uA, you may be better off with the linear regulator. Also, if you have various power states, it may be that an always on linear regulator can supply power in the lowest power state, and the processor can wake up from that state an enable a DC-DC when higher power is needed.